# Superman or Superboy comic from before 1975: Flashback to Clark's college days and device that gave him increased brainpower

Tags: story-identification, dc

When I was a kid in the 1970s, I ran across an older relative's Superman comic collection (the guy who originally owned them was born in the 1940s, I think, so the story was probably from the 1950s or early 1960s).  One story that stuck in my mind was about a group of college friends of Clark that had performed some ceremony/used some device that gave Clark their unused mental capabilities (the old "humans only use 10% of their brain power" notion), but (I think) also connected him to them in some way. They didn't know he was Superman, though.  That part of the story is told in flashback.  The main story is in the present, with the friends coming back together perhaps to use their control of Clark in some way.  It creeped young-me out a bit, so I may not have finished reading that story.

Does anyone else recall this story, and have any additional info about it?

Comment: Read that one too.  I think the professor was involved somehow, maybe he was an alien.

Comment: More likely a Superboy comic. Those were set more often at college than the Superman ones.

Comment: Thanks both of you - could certainly have been a Superbly issue and now that you mention it, I think a professor was experimenting on his students

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I always thought it was significant that despite Superman's physical powers being literally millions or even billions of times what is possessed by humans, his mental ability is within human range -- I am not sure, but I think some humans are actually more intelligent than Superman. Am I right about this?

Comment: There are some signs that Superman is somewhat smarter than an average human - he knows many languages (in a recent episode of Superman and Lois he picked up the trick of talking backwards on BizarroWorld in a few moments) - but there are humans definitely smarter than Supes)

Comment: I think that the story in question was a lot more recent than the poster thinks, maybe seventies era.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to throw out Superman v1 #350.  The name of the story was "Clark Kent's Vanishing Classmates". The story is continued in issue 351 and is from Aug, 1980.  That's outside your timeframe, I know, but it does check most of your boxes. I'm including a single page from the story highlighting the 10% of the brain aspect.[image]

Comment: That's very close - and I'm will to allow that I may be conflating an early 1970s exposure to some Superman stories with a much later exposure to them - but though the image of hovering heads is very familiar this story doesn't seem to have a flashback to an earlier experiment or a psychic connection to Clark.  I wonder if #350 is a reworking/variation on an earlier story.  +1 though for a helpful answer.

Comment: Check the second part in #351.  The malfunctioning of the whole thing was due to the fact that Clark, being Superman, wasn't vulnerable to the experiment.  But, of course, DC was known for, shall we say, recycling story ideas.